# Cython prange variable scope

Tags: parallel-processing, scope, range, cython

I have a function optimized from python that I am trying to parallelize using prange. Local variables are defined and initialized in the top of the function - followed by a prange that manipulates the local variables. However, I get compiler errors saying that the initialized variables aren't assigned any value. If I change prange to a standard range, everything compiles and runs fine.

The function in question (taken from a larger file):

```
#cython: language_level=3
cimport cython
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray
from cython.parallel import prange
from libc.math cimport fabs

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef double curveanalysis(double[:] curve, double[:] outlier):
     cdef double cursign
     cdef double newsign
     cdef int c
     cdef double curmax
     cdef double curoutlier
     cdef double quality
     cdef double curstart
     cdef int curvelen
     cursign = 1.0
     newsign = 1.0
     if curve[0] !=0:
         cursign = curve[0]/fabs(curve[0])
     quality = 0
     curmax = 0.0
     curoutlier = 0
     curstart = 0.0
     curvelen = len(curve)
     for c in prange(curvelen,nogil = True):
          curoutlier += outlier[c]
          if curve[c] == 0:
               newsign = cursign
          else:
               newsign = curve[c]/fabs(curve[c])
          if newsign != cursign:
               quality += curmax*curoutlier/(c-curstart)
               cursign = newsign
               curoutlier = 0
               curmax = fabs(curve[c])
               curstart = c
          elif fabs(curve[c]) >= curmax:
               curmax = fabs(curve[c])
     return quality
```

When I try to compile the program, I get thrown four error message that some of the local variables are unassigned:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
curstart = 0.0
curvelen = len(curve)
for c in prange(curvelen,nogil = True):
    curoutlier += outlier[c]
    if curve[c] == 0:
        newsign = cursign
                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

mastercurveprocessing.pyx:46:22: local variable 'cursign' referenced before assignment
```

This happens for curmax and curstart as well. Some variables, like quality and curoutlier gives no additional compiler errors. I haven't seen this before when using prange, does prange somehow change the scope of assigned variables? What am I missing? As said above, when I change prange to a range everything runs fine (though not in parallel).

I am using Cython version 0.29.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you are assigning to those variables within the loop body and they become lastprivate. The following excerpt from the [Cython documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html) tells you which variable gets which OpenMP data-sharing attribute class:

> **If you assign to a variable in a prange block, it becomes lastprivate, meaning that the variable will contain the value from the last iteration.** If you use an inplace operator on a variable, it becomes a reduction, meaning that the values from the thread-local copies of the variable will be reduced with the operator and assigned to the original variable after the loop. The index variable is always lastprivate. Variables assigned to in a parallel with block will be private and unusable after the block, as there is no concept of a sequentially last value.

Lastprivate variables are local private copies of their original counterparts outside the parallel loop, where the original is assigned the value of the copy from the thread that did the last logical loop iteration. They do not have initial values, unlike firstprivate variables that get initialised to the value of the original variable, which is why you get the errors.

Since you have no control over the inference of the data-sharing classes, you need to rewrite the code somehow. Actually, your problem is hard to parallelise since each iteration depends on the previous one, which means they have to be executed in a strict sequential order, which is not compatible with executing them as independent iteration chunks in parallel.

Comment: So one way would be computing sign-changes first in a separate loop, and in a separate loop compute distinct values between each sign-change? I am wondering if that would create more overhead than is worth it?

Comment: That's one option. Or you may try to solve the problem as several independent subproblems and then somehow tie the solutions together by fixing things in the border regions.

Comment: In the end - for this particular problem - I was capable of getting a substantial cut in computation time by making the entire 'curveanalysis' function nogil, and do the paralellization in processor-intense loops that were much easier to parallelize, which called this particular function. Realizing what loops are best suited for parallelization was helpful.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Finding out the correct place to parallelise the code is the most important part of the whole process.